# Cómo obtener el contenido de un elemento html incluido el codigo del gestor de plantillas de django?

Tags: html, jquery, django

quiero obtener un el contenido de un elemento html propio; dentro del elemento html también se se encuentra código del gestor de plantillas de django, debo obtener ese código para editarlo desde el front. He estado buscando referencia de como realizar esto sin éxito.

```
<code-block>
    {% for item in data %}
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <figure>
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../static/img/bus.jpg" alt="Tepsa">
                    <figcaption><p>{{ item.name }}</p><p>﻿ 533-1524</p><p><a href="">Ver Más</a></p></figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
</code-block>
```

He probado obtener el contenido del elemento usando el siguiente codigo

```
function readCode(){
        var code = $("code").html()
        console.log(code)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas cerca pero tu etiqueta se llama **code-block** y estas accediendo a ese elemento html con **code**
Aquí te dejo un ejemplo-demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   function readCode(){
       code = $("#content").html()
       return code
   }
   
   console.log(readCode())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <code-block>
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
    <p>Parrafo</p>
  </code-block>
</div>
```

No te preocupes por lo que se genera a traves de los template de django ya que al poner `$(document).ready` jquery entra en acción cuando la pagina ha terminado de renderizar y este lista.

Comment: Si, tienes razón con el la etiqueta, pero también necesito obtener el  código del template de django  ya que ese código debo editarlo desde el front

Comment: Cual es el código que quieres capturar

Comment: Quiero capturar todo el código que este dentro de la etiqueta code-block incluido el código de django template. Cuando leo el contenido de la etiqueta no me muestra nada, eso es por el código de django no se reconoce; lo que quiero hacer es leer en si el código django en si para editarlo desde el front.

Comment: Te refieres al? `{% for item in data %}{% endfor %}` y al `{{ item.name }}` eso no se puede hacer con jquery, jquery captura el codigo html generado por el template de django